# Captcha not working properly, still allowing posts

Tags: php, wordpress, captcha

I have a WordPress blog with a forum, and I ONLY want Guests (unregistered users) to be able to post to the forum.  The plugin that I'm using features captcha for just this purpose, but when I tried to post without entering the captcha code, I got "Security Code doesn't Match" and the post went up anyway.

From the file where captcha is handled:

```
if($options['forum_captcha'] == true && !$user_ID){
    if(($_SESSION['security_code'] == $_POST['security_code']) && (!empty($_SESSION['security_code'])) ) {
  unset($_SESSION['security_code']);
    }
    else {
        $error = true;
        $msg = __("Security code does not match", "vasthtml");
    }
}
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Is there a reason your are building you own system instead of using an existing plugin?

Comment: @mikerobi This is from an existing plugin.  I haven't altered a thing.

Comment: This looks odd to me, recaptcha should be returning whether the challenge passed or not, you shouldn't have to check the security code yourself, just the response from the recaptcha server. Check out http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/wordpress.html, might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the input.  I was able to fix the plugin by doin' this:

```
if($options['forum_captcha'] == true && !$user_ID){
    if(($_SESSION['security_code'] == $_POST['security_code']) && (!empty($_SESSION['security_code'])) ) {
  unset($_SESSION['security_code']);
    }
    else {
        $error = true;
        $msg = __("Security code does not match", "vasthtml");
        wp_die($msg);
    }
}
```

Yea, it's a wacky way to utilize captcha, but it's working now.  Vast HTML owes me one!